# Retrieval of secrets in Azure App Service from Hashicorp Vault using Managed Identity | Missing Role - Error

Tags: jwt, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, hashicorp-vault, azure-managed-identity

Hashicorp Vault is the native product of our organization and is a widely used and recommended approach for storing all the key-value pairs or any secrets. Any applications that are deployed on Azure too must store/retrieve the token from Hashicorp Vault and not from the Azure Key Vault. I provided this information just to add a bit of background to the requirement.

Now coming to the actual problem, I deployed the dotnet application on Azure App Service, enable the system-managed identity, and was able to successfully retrieve the JWT token.

As per the flow which I understood by reading the documentation, it says, first retrieve the application token deployed on Azure having System Managed Identity enabled. Once this is done, pass this token for validation to Vault which gets it validated using OIDC from AAD. On successful validation, I will be given back the Vault token which can be used to fetch the secrets from Vault.

To perform these steps configuration is required at the Vault side, for which, I performed all the below steps on the vault server installed on my windows local machine:-

> Command line operation
>
> 1. Start the Vault server
> 2. Open the other command prompt and set the environment variables set
>    VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200 set
>    VAULT_TOKEN=s.iDdVbLKPCzmqF2z0RiXPMxLk
> 3. vault auth enable jwt
> 4. vault write auth/jwt/config
>    oidc_discovery_url=https://sts.windows.net/4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60/
>    bound_issuer=https://sts.windows.net/4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60/
> 5. vault read auth/jwt/config
>    [image]
>    **Policy associated with the sqlconnection:-**
>
> [image]

> **create a role (webapp-role) by using the command**

> curl --header “X-Vault-Token: %VAULT_TOKEN%” --insecure --request POST
> --data @C:\Users\48013\source\repos\HashVaultAzure\Vault-files\payload.json
> %VAULT_ADDR%/v1/auth/jwt/role/webapp-role

```
–payload.json { “bound_audiences”: “https://management.azure.com/”,
 “bound_claims”: { “idp”:
 “https://sts.windows.net/4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60/”,
 “oid”: “8d2b99fb-f4f4-4afb-9ee3-276891f40a65”, “tid”:
 “4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60/” }, “bound_subject”:
 “8d2b99fb-f4f4-4afb-9ee3-276891f40a65”, “claim_mappings”: { “appid”:
 “application_id”, “xms_mirid”: “resource_id” }, “policies”:
 [“sqlconnection”], “role_type”: “jwt”, “token_bound_cidrs”:
 [“10.0.0.0/16”], “token_max_ttl”: “24h”, “user_claim”: “sub” }
```

> **Vault read auth/jwt/role/webapp-role**
>
> [image]
>
> 7. Run the command below with the JWT token retrieved from the application (having the managed identity enabled) deployed on Azure
>    AAD and pass it as “your_jwt”. This command should return the vault
>    token as shown in the link https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/jwt
>
> curl --request POST --data '{"jwt": "your_jwt", "role":
> "webapp-role"}' http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/jwt/login
>
> At this point I receive an error – “Missing Role”,

> [image]
> I am stuck here and not able to find any solution.
>
> Expected response should be a vault token/client_token as shown:-

> [image]

**JWT Token decoded information**

```
 {
  "aud": "https://management.azure.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60/",
  "iat": 1631172032,
  "nbf": 1631172032,
  "exp": 1631258732,
  "aio": "E2ZgYNBN4JVfle92Tsl1b8m8pc9jAA==",
  "appid": "cf5c734c-a4fd-4d85-8049-53de46db4ec0",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60/",
  "oid": "8d2b99fb-f4f4-4afb-9ee3-276891f40a65",
  "rh": "0.AVMAb_GVSro1Ukqcs38wDNwMYExzXM_9pIVNgElT3kbbTsBTAAA.",
  "sub": "8d2b99fb-f4f4-4afb-9ee3-276891f40a65",
  "tid": "4a95f16f-35ba-4a52-9cb3-7f300cdc0c60",
  "uti": "LDjkUZdlKUS4paEleUUFAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_mirid": "/subscriptions/0edeaa4a-d371-4fa8-acbd-3675861b0ac8/resourcegroups/AzureAADResource/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/hashvault-test",
  "xms_tcdt": "1600006540"
}
```

Comment: have you inspect the jtw token ? what s inside it ? Also does the managed identity has been granted access to the Hashicorp  vault ?

Comment: Yes I inspected the JWT token and ensured it has the same oid(Managed Identity ID) which is mentioned in the Vault (Webapp-role). Regarding the other part "the managed identity has been granted access to the Hashicorp vault " - I hope this is achieved while creating the role (webapp-role) and mentioning there the managed Identity ID/OID. I have updated the details with how the webapp-role was created and also shared the JWT decoded token.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the missing configuration both at the Azure Cloud and Vault side.
These were the addition steps done further to make it work.

**Create an Azure SPN** (which is equal to creating an app registration with client secret)

> az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "Hashicorp Vault Prod AzureSPN"
> --skip-assignment Assign as Reader on subscription

**Create Vault config**

> vault auth enable azure vault write auth/jwt/config
> tenant_id=lg240e12-76g1-748b-cd9c-je6f29562476
> resource=https://management.azure.com/ client_id=34906a49-
> 9a8f-462b-9d68-33ae40hgf8ug client_secret=123456ABCDEF